# How to clear the command line?

Tags: rust

Is there a Rust equivalent to the `system` function in the C/C++ standard library? Specifically I am trying to use `cls` to clear the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [C's `system` function](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/libc/funcs/c95/stdlib/fn.system.html) through the [`libc`](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate. But fortunately there's a much better way: [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html).

A quick and dirty way to call `cls` would be

```
if std::process::Command::new("cls").status().unwrap().success() {
    println!("screen successfully cleared");
}
```

Comment: Careful! `cls` only exists on Windows. In *nix, the command is `clear`. In general, it wouldn't be recommendable to use system commands for that. This goes through a lot of work: finding the command, starting the process, binding stdout, etc. I would try to stick to libc in this case.

Comment: I also wonder why this is seen as "better". It's non-portable and a mouthful, what's better about it?

Comment: it's not unsafe and uses Rust's `Result` type to guarantee that you check that it worked. Even if you simply take the program to linux, at least you get a nice failure. If you want a one-liner that runs on all systems you can start chaining the commands: `assert!(Command::new("cls").status().or_else(|_| Command::new("clear")).unwrap().success())`

Comment: I wonder if one of the terminal related crates have a clear command... Couldn't find anything though.

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned methods did not work for me

> The following method works in windows cmd

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
winapi = "0.2.8"
kernel32-sys = "0.2.1"
```

**Code**

```
extern crate kernel32;
extern crate winapi;

use winapi::HANDLE;
use winapi::wincon::CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO;
use winapi::wincon::COORD;
use winapi::wincon::SMALL_RECT;
use winapi::WORD;
use winapi::DWORD;

static mut CONSOLE_HANDLE: Option<HANDLE> = None;


fn get_output_handle() -> HANDLE {
    unsafe {
        if let Some(handle) = CONSOLE_HANDLE {
            return handle;
        } else {
            let handle = kernel32::GetStdHandle(winapi::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            CONSOLE_HANDLE = Some(handle);
            return handle;
        }
    }
}

fn get_buffer_info() -> winapi::CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO {
    let handle = get_output_handle();
    if handle == winapi::INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE {
        panic!("NoConsole")
    }
    let mut buffer = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO {
        dwSize: COORD { X: 0, Y: 0 },
        dwCursorPosition: COORD { X: 0, Y: 0 },
        wAttributes: 0 as WORD,
        srWindow: SMALL_RECT {
            Left: 0,
            Top: 0,
            Right: 0,
            Bottom: 0,
        },
        dwMaximumWindowSize: COORD { X: 0, Y: 0 },
    };
    unsafe {
        kernel32::GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handle, &mut buffer);
    }
    buffer
}

fn clear() {
    let handle = get_output_handle();
    if handle == winapi::INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE {
        panic!("NoConsole")
    }

    let screen_buffer = get_buffer_info();
    let console_size: DWORD = screen_buffer.dwSize.X as u32 * screen_buffer.dwSize.Y as u32;
    let coord_screen = COORD { X: 0, Y: 0 };

    let mut amount_chart_written: DWORD = 0;
    unsafe {
        kernel32::FillConsoleOutputCharacterW(
            handle,
            32 as winapi::WCHAR,
            console_size,
            coord_screen,
            &mut amount_chart_written,
        );
    }
    set_cursor_possition(0, 0);
}

fn set_cursor_possition(y: i16, x: i16) {
    let handle = get_output_handle();
    if handle == winapi::INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE {
        panic!("NoConsole")
    }
    unsafe {
        kernel32::SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, COORD { X: x, Y: y });
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
fn main() {
    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        println!("You typed: {}", input);

        if input.trim() == "clear" {
            clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the other comments worked for me either. This worked. But it might be a notable mention for others that you might need to do something like `for _ in 0..screen_buffer.dwSize.Y { println!(""); }` after `let coord_screen = COORD { X: 0, Y: 0 };`. Why? Because this posted method doesn't ALWAYS clear everything, but if you output newlines it will definitely clear everything. I had special color blocks that weren't cleared by this method, although ascii text was

Answer (score 0):

*oli_obk*, actually I think this is correct - it worked for me with Rust on Linux:

```
assert!( std::process::Command::new("cls").status().or_else(|_| std::process::Command::new("clear").status()).unwrap().success() );
```

`status()` has to be used twice.
(Put the code line above inside a function like main.)